# How to solve the sawtooth pattern? Issues in ggplot2 line chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is the datasets and code, I am trying to make a line chart to show the growth of prison population by states. The code I have now works fine if I only examine one state, but once I put multiple states into the function, it returns a sawtooth pattern, which goes sudden up and down.

```
get_jail_pop_by_states <- function(states) {
  state_growth <- incarceration_trends %>% 
    select(total_jail_pop, year, state)
  select_state <- state_growth %>% 
    filter(state == states)
  return(select_state)   
}

View(get_jail_pop_by_states("MO"))

plot_jail_pop_by_states <- function(states) {
  p <- ggplot(get_jail_pop_by_states(states), aes(x=year, y=total_jail_pop, color= state))+
    stat_summary(fun.y="mean", geom= "line") +
    xlab("Year") + 
    ylab("Total jail popultion") + 
    ggtitle("Growth of Prison Population by State")

  return(p)
}
plot_jail_pop_by_states(c("CA","WA", "OR"))
```

Here is the data set:

[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YiuNw.png)

And here is the graph I got:
[sawtooth graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kUJ7.png)

Any advice or suggestions will be huge help! Thank you!

Comment: We can't reproduce graphs from screenshots of data! Try either putting a sample using `dput` or generating a synthetic dataset. We'd love to help but seems like something in your data not being handled correctly :)

Comment: And your dataset provides data from only one state.  Since your problem appears only when attempting to plot more than one state, that's not sufficient.  ou maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.

Comment: Also, `filter(state == states)` will fail when `states` is a vector rather than a scalar.  You will need `filter(state %in% states)` instead.  Please correct the typo, and amend your question if the problem persists.

Comment: @AndyBaxter Thank you for the reminder Andy! I think I just figured out, all I need was changed "==" to "%in%" in filter!

Comment: @Limey Thank you so much Limey! It actually worked! I think just like you said it is a vector rather than a scalar. Sorry for the confusion in the question. Thank you so much. Stack overflow is amazing